# Would Changing the Installation key of the Second Generation Managed Package needs once again approval from Salesforce

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review, second-generation-packaging, change-password

We have published our Second Generation Managed Package in AppExchange Portal after approval from Salesforce. But we want to update the installation key of the Package. Would it needs approval once again from Salesforce, if we change the installation key?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9065d000000Xcjm), by installation key, you are referring to the password of the package. Changing this password shouldn't have any effect or require the package to undergo approval again since it's the same package id that already has a passed flag.